# weak-derivative of $u\in H^{3/2}(\Omega)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to show that if $u\in H^{3/2}(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ a bounded Lipschitz domain, then $Du \in H^{1/2}$ where $Du$ is the weak derivative of $u$.

I'm new to fractional Sobolev spaces and this should be an easy problem. I would appreciate if someone can help me with it. Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of $H^{3/2}(\Omega)$? Often, this is defined via $u$ has a weak derivative $Du$ and $Du \in H^{1/2}(\Omega)$.

Comment: I am following the book "Hitchhiker's guide to fractional Sobolev spaces" and the definition of $H^{3/2}$ is
$ H^{3/2}(\Omega) =  \{ u\in L^2(\Omega) : \int_\Omega \int_\Omega \frac{u(x) - u(y)}{|x-y|^{3/2}} \in L^{2}(\Omega \times \Omega) \}$.

Your suggestion makes sense to me. I'm not entirely sure if it is in the assumption that $Du$ is in $H^{1/2}$.

Comment: I had the idea to multiply the derivative with the test function and integrate as this 

$$\int_\Omega \int_\Omega \frac{Du \cdot \phi(x) - Du \cdot \phi(x)}{|x - y|^{1/2}}  $$
$$ = \int_\Omega \int_\Omega \frac{u \cdot \phi'(x) - u \cdot \phi'(x)}{|x - y|^{1/2}}   $$
$$ =  (\text{not entirely sure}) =  \int_\Omega \int_\Omega \frac{u \cdot \phi(x) - u \cdot \phi(x)}{|x - y|^{3/2}} < \infty $$